How to access provider value in Angular 19
Using Angular SSR, I would like to access a server-side value in my app.component.
Here is my server-side route:
app.get('**', (req, res, next) => {
  const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

  commonEngine
    .render({
      bootstrap,
      documentFilePath: indexHtml,
      url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
      publicPath: browserDistFolder,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
          useValue: baseUrl
        },
        {
          provide: 'message',
          useValue: 'Message provided server-side'
        }
      ],
    })
    .then((html) => res.send(html))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
});

I am providing a value: message
Here's my component code, where I would like to pick up the message value.
@Component({
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
  ],
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    @Optional()
    @Inject('message')
    readonly message: string,

    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID)
    private readonly platformId: Object,

    private transferState: TransferState,
  ) {
    const MESSAGE_KEY = makeStateKey<string>('message');

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.message = this.transferState.get(MESSAGE_KEY, 'Message provided client-side');
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.message); // this value is null

      this.transferState.set(MESSAGE_KEY, this.message);
    }
  }
}

message is always null.
Here's my app.config where I'm specifying client hydration:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(withEventReplay())
  ]
};

Here's the app.config.server
const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
  ]
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

What is the correct way to access provided values?

The new angular 19 scaffolding comes with this server.ts here which uses this new AngularNodeAppEngine instead of the CommonEngine. I have yet to find out how to inject the providers in this new implementation of the dev server. The answer you marked as correct allows you to add providers from the main.server.ts, but you can't get the req and res from the exrpress application's scope from there.

You need to add the providers at the app.config.ts, adding two different values for main.ts(app.config.ts) and main.server.ts(app.config.server.ts).
app.config.ts
import {
  ApplicationConfig,
  InjectionToken,
  makeEnvironmentProviders,
  provideZoneChangeDetection,
} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export const MESSAGE = new InjectionToken<string>('message'); // <- this must be on the app.config.ts (!important)

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    { provide: MESSAGE, useValue: 'message from the browser' },
  ],
};

app.config.server.ts
import {
  mergeApplicationConfig,
  ApplicationConfig,
  InjectionToken,
} from '@angular/core';
import { provideServerRendering } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { appConfig, MESSAGE } from './app.config';

const serverConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideServerRendering(),
    { provide: MESSAGE, useValue: 'message from the server' },
  ],
};

export const config = mergeApplicationConfig(appConfig, serverConfig);

app.component.ts
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { MESSAGE } from './app.config';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';
  message = inject(MESSAGE, {
    optional: true,
  });
  platformId = PLATFORM_ID;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      console.log('from browser', this.message);
    } else {
      console.log('from server', this.message);
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm i -> npm run start

Thank you. That does work, and I'm even able to pick up values from the process. Next step is to see if I can get those values into a service that I can provide to other components.

This is fantastic. I can pick up the same values in service classes, and when those services are spec'd in deps for other providers, they are populated as expected.

Where/how do you inject the RESPONSE and REQUEST from here on?

@AlexPappas you can refer this answer for some code reference

@NarenMurali I know about this and this only works with using CommonEngine which has issue passing anything in the providers parameter from express (server.ts) to the angular app. This was supposedly addressed on version 19, by adding "outputMode": "server" in angular.json, however it also must come with the new way of writing server.ts which uses the new AngularNodeAppEngine instead of CommonEngine, which I do not see any example of adding providers in. Refer here

In v18, the vite dev-server doesn't not rely on the server.ts config, it has its own configuration.
This behavior has been improved in v19.
So you have 2 solutions:

Either you're always in prod-mode with a prod-build
You update to v19.


I'm actually using v19 for this. I added the app.config.server to my question. Do I need to add a provider or different options?
